# Windows Server 2008 R2 Product Updates

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update, ms-security-essentials

I installed and then uninstalled Microsoft Security Essentials on Server 2008 R2 - after installation I noticed that there were 12 updates on a supposedly fully updated system.  I did a little further comparison with another Server 2008 R2 server and noticed that after installing MSE I now have an extra option titled "Microsoft Update - Give me updates for Microsoft products and check for new optional Microsoft software when I update window".  How can I enable this on regular Server 2008 R2 installation without installing MSE?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Update, if you go to change settings on the left, you will see a checkbox under the title "Microsoft Update". That's the one you want.